# AES encryption on iphone

Tags: iphone, encryption, aes

This is karthik,

I would like to implement aes encryption method on my iphone application . Already I have done it with some problem . I had encrypted the string successfully and I can send it to java server to decrypt it. But they cannot decrypt it to original string . As the same , They encrypt some data and have send it to me. Me too cannot decrypt it. Can anyone please suggest me? to solve this problem. I am trying to fix this issue for last 4 days. So please help me...

```
 Is there any tutorial to implement aes both on java and iphone?
```

Comment: If the same encryption algorithm is used along with the same key size and mode of operation, the programming language does not matter. I am pretty sure that you are not using the same key size and most possibly the same mode of operation. Please post the code you are currently using for the iphone implementation and the server implementation so someone and take a look and see what you are doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone, you have OpenSSL available. You can google for various examples on how to do AES with it, like [this one](http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt).